# django remove m2m instance when there are no more relations

Tags: python-3.x, django, m2m

In case we had the model:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

According to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/, to create an object we must have both objects saved before we can create the relation:

```
p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
p1.save()
a1 = Article(headline='Django lets you build web apps easily')
a1.save()
a1.publications.add(p1)
```

Now, if we called `delete` in either of those objects the object would be removed from the DB along with the relation between both objects. Up until this point I understand.

But is there any way of doing that, if an `Article` is removed, then, all the `Publications` that are not related to any `Article` will be deleted from the DB too? Or the only way to achieve that is to query first all the Articles and then iterate through them like:

```
to_delete = []
qset = a1.publications.all()
for publication in qset:
    if publication.article_set.count() == 1:
        to_delete(publication.id)
a1.delete()
Publications.filter(id__in=to_delete).delete()
```

But this has lots of problems, specially a concurrency one, since it might be that a `publication` gets used by another `article` between the call to `.count()` and `publication.delete()`.

Is there any way of doing this automatically, like doing a "conditional" `on_delete=models.CASCADE` when creating the model or something?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to remove the related objects from DB, then you can simply call `delete`: `publication.article_set.delete()`, if you want to unlink the related objects, then call `clear`: `publication.article_set.clear()`

Comment: I would like to call the `delete()` function on all Articles that are not referenced by other `Publication` avoiding any concurrency issues

Comment: Then you could probably do it with `annotate` and `Count`: `Publication.objects.annotate(article_count=Count('article_set')).filter(article_count=1).delete()`

Comment: @Ersain that would be `article_count=0` after deleting the article (generalized tidy-up), or you need to filter only `publications.filter(article=a1).annotate(...` before `a1.delete()`

Comment: @nigel222 or `a1.publications.annotate(article_count=Count('article_set')).filter(article_count=1).delete()`

Comment: @Ersain I don't really understand what the `Count` class does. Would it be possible to get an answer with a short explanation of both `Count` and `annotate`? As far as I understand `annotate` just executes the following function calls to all elements of the `QuerySet`, is that right? So in this case it will execute the filter+delete to all these elements.

Comment: @nigel222 any idea why the `article_set` is not being found in the Article? Only `article, id, title` exist

Comment: Possibly I'm wrong about the implicit name. It might be article or articles. Consult the docs, or set it explicitly on the other model using related_name=whatever on the ManyToMany field definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with @Ersain answer:

```
a1.publications.annotate(article_count=Count('article_set')).filter(article_count=1).delete()
```

Couldn't make it work. First of all, I couldn't find the `article_set` variable in the relationship.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'article_set' into field. Choices are: article, id, title

And then, running the count filter on the QuerySet after filtering by article returned ALL the tags from the article, instead of just the ones with `article_count=1`. So finally this is the code that I managed to make it work with:

```
Publication.objects.annotate(article_count=Count('article')).filter(article_count=1).filter(article=a1).delete()
```

Definetly I'm not an expert, not sure if this is the best approach nor if it is really time expensive, so I'm open to suggestions. But as of now it's the only solution I found to perform this operation atomically.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the related objects using this query:

```
a1.publications.annotate(article_count=Count('article_set')).filter(article_count=1).delete()
```

`annotate` creates a temporary field for the queryset (alias field) which aggregates a number of related `Article` objects for each instance in the queryset of `Publication` objects, using `Count` function. `Count` is a built-in aggregation function in any SQL, which returns the number of rows from a query (a number of related instances in this case). Then, we filter out those results where `article_count` equals 1 and remove them.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps and found a few issues. First of all, in my model I have a `Card` which has a `m2m` relation with `Tag`, which only contains a `CharField name`.

The call `card.tags.annotate(card_count=Count('card_set')).filter(card_count=1).delete()` produces this error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'card_set' into field. Choices are: card, id, name`. If I set it as `card` instead of `card_set`, no exception is thrown, but all the `tags` used by this card get removed, despite other cards using those tags too, so the filter is not executed.

Comment: This is how I put in `Card` model: `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)` so no `related_name` field. Not sure what `card_set` is not in there. And then again, not sure why the filter is not being executed.

Comment: Tried with the Django shell. Created two cards with tags `[aa, bb]` and `[aa, cc]`: `Tag.objects.annotate(card_count=Count('card'))` results in `QuerySet [<Tag: aa>, <Tag: bb>, <Tag: cc>]`. If I filter: `Tag.objects.annotate(card_count=Count('card')).filter(card_count=1)` it shows correctly `QuerySet [<Tag: bb>, <Tag: cc>]`. But if I do it with the card:
`card1.tags.annotate(card_count=Count('card'))` -> `<QuerySet [<Tag: aa>, <Tag: bb>]>` and adding the `.filter(card_count=1)` returns `QuerySet [<Tag: aa>, <Tag: bb>]`. So clearly the filter is not applied when looking from the card objects.